# Can't view S3 Bucket files in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Whenever trying to view S3 Bucket files in my browser, I see this:

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.</Message>
<ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>null</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>XXXX</RequestId>
<HostId>XXXXXXXXXXXX</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have no idea what this means and cannot find much information on Google or SO on this. Any help is appreciated. I'm simply trying to view an image file in my browser that sits in my S3 Bucket.

Comment: " view S3 Bucket files in my browser" - what do you mean? Using AWS S3 console?

Comment: I have a jpg file that I'm trying to view in browser but when I click on the provided link I get this.

Comment: Are you able to download that file ?

Comment: It is saying that the URL used to view the image is invalid. Where did you get the URL? Can you show us the URL you used? (Feel free to change your bucket name for privacy purposes.)